# STM FDCAN Rx has wrong DataLength value

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, can-bus, hal

### The problem

I am trying to receive a CAN message using FDCAN on my STM32H723 uController. But when I call the function `HAL_FDCAN_GetRxMessage(hfdcan, FDCAN_RX_FIFO0, &CAN1RxHeader, CAN1Rx_buffer);` the value in `CAN1RxHeader.DataLength` is not what one would expect; i.e. DataLength is not a byte value representing message size, it is some massive number.

Please see below answer for solution to this problem.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: No question, sharing the solution to a problem. Clarified that in my post

Comment: I think it is ok to ask a question and then answer it yourself (in an answer). But this will just show up to people as a question with no answer, and they probably won't even read it.

Comment: When posting this, there is a button you can click "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style" - then you can type in the question first and the answer directly below it.

Comment: You know, it is insane that when people add solutions to the community to then get negative reviews. Dont you get that that simply discourages people to help and add solutions. Good to know Lundin. Noted for the next time. I have tried, dont believe I can change it anymore.

Comment: @misha As you must know, this is a question and answer website. People ask questions and give answers. It's not Reddit, where you just post stuff. You're welcome to answer your own questions. But maybe someone else will come up with an even better answer! I removed my DV since you've at least split your answer off into an actual answer. (You still don't really ask a question, but we get the idea.)

Answer (score 1):

To get the actual value of the size, you need to bit shift the value in `CAN1RxHeader.DataLength`. See below example:

```
void HAL_FDCAN_RxFifo0Callback(FDCAN_HandleTypeDef *hfdcan, uint32_t RxFifo0ITs)
{
    /* Prevent unused argument(s) compilation warning */
    UNUSED(hfdcan);
    UNUSED(RxFifo0ITs);
    
    uint8_t CAN1Rx_buffer[8];
    HAL_FDCAN_GetRxMessage(hfdcan, FDCAN_RX_FIFO0, &CAN1RxHeader, CAN1Rx_buffer);
    uint32_t len = CAN1RxHeader.DataLength >> 16;
}
```

To find the reason why this is you will need to look in stm32h7xx_hal_fdcan.h, or your chip equivalent. Have a look at the GetRxMessage function. In here you will see the mask value and the memory location in question. We however need to look at the bytes 16-19 to obtain out 32bit DataLength value.

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_FDCAN_GetRxMessage(FDCAN_HandleTypeDef *hfdcan, uint32_t RxLocation, FDCAN_RxHeaderTypeDef *pRxHeader, uint8_t *pRxData)
{
    //...
    
    /* Retrieve DataLength */
    pRxHeader->DataLength = (*RxAddress & FDCAN_ELEMENT_MASK_DLC);

    //...
}
```

I hope this helps if you happen to run into the same problem.

Comment: Worked for me here! I'm using FDCAN interface on M4 MCU of STM32MP157 here. Thanks a lot Misha